# Como cambiar una columna de mi base de datos con Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Accidentalmente trabajando con rails nombre mal una
columna de mi tabla pagos ya que quería llamarla Entrantes y  le la termine
llamando ntrantes.

Mi pregunta es: ¿Cómo puedo cambiar el nombre de la columna con
las migraciones? o ¿tiene que ser manual desde la base de datos?

Comment: ¿Sólo es un error en esa columna o deseas modificar otras?

Comment: Hola! Sí es que solo me equivoque en esa columna y no se que manera sea la mejor para arreglarlo, agradecería mucho la ayuda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de las 2 formas, si lo haces de la base de datos tendrás que cambiarlo manualmente y después actualizarlo con un `rails db:schema:dump`.

Para actualizar tu `schema`, sin embargo, tendrás que modificar los modelos y controladores. Si por otro lado gustas hacerlo con una migración, necesitarás primero generarla con:

```
rails generate migration cambiando_columna
```

... y en la migración que te genero poner lo siguiente (está mal en `rename_colum`, es `rename_column`):

```
class CambiandoColumna< ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
 def change
    rename_column :pagos, :ntrantes, :Entrantes
 end
end
```

... y al terminar de modificar esta migración simplemente poner el comando `rails db:migrate` para que este cambio tome efecto.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda! preferí utilizar la migración y todo quedo al 100, de nuevo gracias